# Obtener lat y lng con AJAX y cargarlo en un mapa de google

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Buenas estoy intentando llenar un mapa con clusters, estoy trayendo las localizaciones de la base de datos con AJAX, luego creo una variable que ya contiene todo para rellenarlo y hago un push para poder usarlo en la función de `initMAP`, pero me sale nada. Os muestro que estoy haciendo.

Defino la variable centros, y luego con la información que traigo por AJAX genero lo que necesita google maps.

```
var centros = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({                        
            type: "GET",                 
            url : "{{URL::to('/centros')}}",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data)            
            {
                for(var i=0;i<data.centros.length;i++) 
                {
                  centros.push('{lat: '+ data.centros[i].latitud +', lng: '+ data.centros[i].longitud +'},');
                }
                //console.log(centros);
             }
    });
});
```

Luego envio el parametro `centros a la siguiente función` y cargo los centros ahí.

```
function initMap(centros) {
        
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: 39.2033565, lng: -0.3113277999999582},
        });
        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        const labels = "C";
        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        const markers = locations.map((location, i) => {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length],
          });
        });
        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
          imagePath:
            "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
        });
      }
      
      const locations = centros
      console.log(locations);
```

El `console.log(locations);` lo que me trae es lo siguiente.

```
[]
0: "{lat: 39.4718655, lng: -0.3840513},"
1: "{lat: 38.8421981, lng: -0.113122},"
2: "{lat: 38.9939887, lng: -0.5172643},"
3: "{lat: 38.9630974, lng: -0.58739},"
4: "{lat: 39.390369, lng: -0.7124376},"
5: "{lat: 39.4247713, lng: -0.4665065},"
6: "{lat: 39.4535737, lng: -0.4064579},"
7: "{lat: 39.150306, lng: -0.4407379},"
8: "{lat: 39.5180665, lng: -0.377204},"
9: "{lat: 39.47136, lng: -0.7178069},"
10: "{lat: 39.0369313, lng: -0.6596856},"
11: "{lat: 39.518195, lng: -0.4238217},"
12: "{lat: 38.9921306, lng: -0.5256887},"
13: "{lat: 39.5733856, lng: -0.3316215},"
14: "{lat: 39.5635474, lng: -0.2871925},"
15: "{lat: 39.5016194, lng: -0.4441376},"
16: "{lat: 39.4948569, lng: -0.468224},"
17: "{lat: 39.4616046, lng: -0.4601335},"
18: "{lat: 39.8465105, lng: -0.4892299},"
19: "{lat: 40.4695856, lng: 0.4677703},"
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Pero no carga nada en el mapa, que puede ser???

---

Si cargo manualmente en la variable centros, esto. A la vez que cargo los mios, si hay una diferencia:

```
  { lat: -31.56391, lng: 147.154312 },
  { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
```

Los que pongo manualmente parece texto plano y lo otro un obejeto:

```
21: {lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438}
22:
lat: -43.999792
lng: 170.463352
__proto__: Object
23: "{ lat: 39.4718655, lng: -0.3840513 },"
24: "{ lat: 38.8421981, lng: -0.113122 },"
```

Si os fijais se pueden abrir, esos si funcionan pero los mios no, tengo que pasarlo a un obejto? he probado pero sin acierto.

---

**Actualización**

Muestro como lo tengo ahora, aunque sigue sin funcionar. Lo único que he cambiado es el success del AJAX.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.centros.length;i++) 
   {
     var lat = data.centros[i].latitud;
     var lng = data.centros[i].longitud;
     centros.push({"lat": parseFloat(lat), "lng": parseFloat(lng)});     
    }
```

Lo que veo es que en el console.log(centros), en la consola de chrome, me sale así:

```
->[] // Una vez le hago click si que salen todos los resultados.
```

En cambio si relleno la variable `centros` manualmente me sale así:

```
->(23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

**El AJAX me trae directamente esto**

```
{centros: Array(20)}
centros: Array(20)
0: {latitud: "39.4718655", longitud: "-0.3840513"}
1: {latitud: "38.8421981", longitud: "-0.113122"}
2: {latitud: "38.9939887", longitud: "-0.5172643"}
3: {latitud: "38.9630974", longitud: "-0.58739"}
4: {latitud: "39.390369", longitud: "-0.7124376"}
5: {latitud: "39.4247713", longitud: "-0.4665065"}
6: {latitud: "39.4535737", longitud: "-0.4064579"}
7: {latitud: "39.150306", longitud: "-0.4407379"}
8: {latitud: "39.5180665", longitud: "-0.377204"}
9: {latitud: "39.47136", longitud: "-0.7178069"}
10: {latitud: "39.0369313", longitud: "-0.6596856"}
11: {latitud: "39.518195", longitud: "-0.4238217"}
12: {latitud: "38.9921306", longitud: "-0.5256887"}
13: {latitud: "39.5733856", longitud: "-0.3316215"}
14: {latitud: "39.5635474", longitud: "-0.2871925"}
15: {latitud: "39.5016194", longitud: "-0.4441376"}
16: {latitud: "39.4948569", longitud: "-0.468224"}
17: {latitud: "39.4616046", longitud: "-0.4601335"}
18: {latitud: "39.8465105", longitud: "-0.4892299"}
19: {latitud: "40.4695856", longitud: "0.4677703"}
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: A mí me parece que `locations` no está definido cuando intentas usarlo. Prueba con `const markers = centros.map(...)`

Comment: Lo tengo medio solucionado, no hace falta que este definido, el problema es que el arreglo no estaba bien construido, solo tengo que quitarle las comillas al string `23: {lat: "39.4718655", lng: "-0.3840513"}` tengo que quitar esas comillas

Comment: En serio? Pensaba que var era hoisted y const era block scoped, a lo mejor es block scoped a initmap completo

Comment: Sabes como quitar esas comillas, creo que es lo único que falla

Comment: `centros.push({lat:data.centros[i].latitud, lng: data.centros[i].longitud})`

Comment: Mas o menos lo que tengo yo `centros.push({"lat": lat, "lng": lng});` definiendo antes las variables `lat` y `lng` pero tengo que poder quitar esas comillas

Comment: Es que el problema es que en la base de datos esta guardado como `string` por eso las comillas, pero si lo pongo en float me quita números @ffflabs

Comment: Le he quitado las comillas pero sigue sin funcionar, solo carga las de muestra, si quito las de muestra y dejo las mias en la consola sale `[ ]` vacio y cuando le hago clic me lo muestra, pero si dejo las de muestra me sale diferente `(23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` que puede ser @ffflabs

Comment: Estoy confundido. Puedes loguear lo que trae literalmente tu ajax? Y cuéntanos el layout general, porque no entiendo quién invoca a initMap.

Comment: Hola buenos días @ffflabs te añadi a la pregunta lo que trae el AJAX directamente sin pasar por el `for` lo que no entendí  a que te refieres con el layout, si te refireres al resto de página, no hay nada más, si no me equivoco

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta ha tenido tantas iteraciones que ya no sé qué le estás pasando al bucle. En lo medular:  no debes concatenar lo que te llega. Tu enfoque inicial sólo generaba un arreglo de strings

```
 var centros=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.centros.length; i++) {
      centros.push(
      '{lat: ' + data.centros[i].latitud + ', lng: ' + data.centros[i].longitud + '},'
      );
  }
  return centros;
```

Genera algo como

```
    [
     "{lat: 123, lng: 456}," ,
      ...
     "{lat: 789, lng: 1011}," 
    ]
```

El mapa necesita que le pases un  array de objetos, y que cada objeto tenga las propiedades lat y lng, y que el valor de ambas sea un número. Cualquier otro escenario no te dibujará lo que buscas.

A partir de lo que comentas que devuelve tu ajax,

```
 { 
   centros : [
      {latitud: "39.4718655", longitud: "-0.3840513"},
      ...
      {latitud: "40.4695856", longitud: "0.4677703"}
   ]
 }
```

Creo que lo más eficiente es tomar `data` y retornar usando `Array.prototype.map`:

```
return data.centros.map(centro => {
   return {
     lat: Number(centro.latitud),
     lng: Number(centro.longitud)
   };
});
```

Hice un experimento simulando el ajax con una promesa y un timeout.

(lo que no entiendo es en qué parte le metías datos por consola a `centros`, siendo que es una variable interna de la función  `initMap`)

```js
function llamadaAjax() {
   
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        centros: [{
            latitud: "39.4718655",
            longitud: "-0.3840513"
          },
          {
            latitud: "38.8421981",
            longitud: "-0.113122"
          },
          {
            latitud: "38.9939887",
            longitud: "-0.5172643"
          },
          {
            latitud: "38.9630974",
            longitud: "-0.58739"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.390369",
            longitud: "-0.7124376"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.4247713",
            longitud: "-0.4665065"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.4535737",
            longitud: "-0.4064579"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.150306",
            longitud: "-0.4407379"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.5180665",
            longitud: "-0.377204"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.47136",
            longitud: "-0.7178069"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.0369313",
            longitud: "-0.6596856"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.518195",
            longitud: "-0.4238217"
          },
          {
            latitud: "38.9921306",
            longitud: "-0.5256887"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.5733856",
            longitud: "-0.3316215"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.5635474",
            longitud: "-0.2871925"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.5016194",
            longitud: "-0.4441376"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.4948569",
            longitud: "-0.468224"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.4616046",
            longitud: "-0.4601335"
          },
          {
            latitud: "39.8465105",
            longitud: "-0.4892299"
          },
          {
            latitud: "40.4695856",
            longitud: "0.4677703"
          }
        ]
      });

    }, 1500);
  }).then(function(data) {

    return data.centros.map(centro => {
      return {
        lat: Number(centro.latitud),
        lng: Number(centro.longitud)
      };
    });

  });
}

function initMap(centros) {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 39.4718655,
      lng: -0.3
    },
    zoom: 9
  });
  const markers = centros.map((location, i) => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,

      map
    });
  });
}

llamadaAjax().then((centros) => initMap(centros));
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>


<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, seguro que le estare dando muchas vueltas al código, es de las primeras veces que genere el código por mi mismo. Tengo una duda, la variable `centros[]` tiene que estar dentro del `success`?  y por otro lado, en el `for` haces un `return` pero luego más abajo haces otro `return` supongo que habré puesto algo mal, por que me saca un string,  no se si te apetece que lo veamos en un chat, para no alargar esto. Gracias!

Comment: Ah, no, solamente dejé lo que supuse que tenías, y retorné antes sin usar la variable centros. Mejor quito eso

Comment: Y efectivamente, si la variable centros existe en el scope superior, se vuelve confuso que además sea un parámetro de initMap. Eso se llama variable shadowing

Comment: Sigo sin conseguirlo, creo que hay algo que no estoy entendiendo. Podemos pasar el debate a chat y lo vemos con más detención por favor!?

Comment: No puedo, Miguel. Tengo reunión a las 11 y estoy contra el tiempo.

Comment: Bueno voy a estar todo el día por aquí, si puedes en algún momento avisame por favor!

Comment: Hola @ffflabs tienes un hueco para que miremos esto?